# How to send excel file as POST to be handled by a php page

Tags: database, post, dojo, uploader

I have a dijit form that uploads an excel file and sends it via post to upload.php that will load the data of this file to database. The problem I have is that the file is not sent. I work with dojo 1.10.

I've tried xhrPost and iframe but didn't succeed and I didn't understand how to do it and what type of data I should send (is it text??).

```php
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dojoroot/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src='./dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
        <script>
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dojox/form/Uploader", "dojox/form/uploader/plugins/IFrame","dojox/form/uploader/FileList", "dojo/request/iframe", "dojo/domReady!"]);
function sendForm(){
  var form = dojo.byId("uploadForm");

  dojo.connect(form, "onsubmit", function(event){
dojo.stopEvent(event);
var xhrArgs = {
      form: dojo.byId("uploadForm"),
      handleAs: "text",
      load: function(data){
        dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";
      },
      error: function(error){
 dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";
      }
    }
    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form being sent..."
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
  });
}
dojo.ready(sendForm);
        </script>

    </head>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
      <input data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Uploader" name="file" multiple="false" type="file" id="file" label="Browse" data-dojo-props="name:'file',showInput:'before',isDebug:true">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" label="Upload" name="Import" dojoType="dijit/form/Button" />
 <div id="files2" dojoType="dojox/form/uploader/FileList" uploaderId="file"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

In upload.php I have this:

```php
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
....
```

I read dojo documentation, but I couldn't get the point about how to solve my issue. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error inside the form. The input tag with name `import` is actually a button and will not have a value when you send this to the server. So `isset($_POST["Import"])` will return false.

So removing this check will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, the input tag is a submit button. Even though removing the check you mentionned, it doesn't work. When debugging on firebug, I got this error: Error parsing server result: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data"